# RabbitMQ Per-Connection Queue Creation and Deletion

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

I've been adopting RabbitMQ in a new project. I'll need a clustered environment to support system failure and high-demand. On to the problem: queues must be created as exclusive whenever a client connects. If the client disconnects, I want the queue to be deleted, freeing its resources. Furthermore, queue binding to topics must be limited with per-credential permissions.

Concluding, I would like to constraint connection to create only exclusive queues (that would auto-delete when the connection closes) and only bind such queue to a list of topics I would allow, configured per user account.

I'm not being able to either limit queue creation to exclusive, nor limit the topics a client can subscribe to. I could impose this constraint based on VHOSTS, but that would require the dynamic creation of VHOSTS and probably hundreds of them.

Is this possible in RabbitMQ? Is there a better approach to it?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you only want clients to be able to create exclusive queues you may need to write your own wrapper and abstract away RabbitMQ from the clients completely.  Have your clients talk to RabbitMQ through this wrapper and deal with queue creation and binding here.

This would expose your own version of queue_declare which then calls the RabbitMQ queue_declare method setting exlusive=true.

Comment: crappy workaround since it would require way too much work to support multiple languages, but the only way to do so due to the limitations from rabbitmq acl system. I'll probably pre-create each queue and bind it myself appropriately, allowing each user to only read from its own queue.